# How to add an extra Javascript Event Handler for all Input Fields to Log Clicks+Edits?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, logging

The problem that I am trying to solve is that I have a page with many input fields (some of which are generated dynamically), and I want to be able to do some logging for whenever the user is clicking on various input controls and has modified the data, then left the control.  I figure that this can be done by capturing events for onFocus and onBlur, for all types of input fields (buttons, dropdowns, text boxes, etc.).  I expect to log the fact that they entered the element and also the value when they left it. However, I have two restrictions:

1. Some of the inputs have their own event handlers.  I do not want to clobber these, but want to trigger events independently of them.  Since the goal is sending off log messages, there is really no need for my additional event handlers to ever interact with the existing event handlers.
2. I need to have a selector that will allow me to capture all the input controls that currently exist when the user triggers the event (however many that may be).  This could be done at the same time that the event fires, or it could be triggered to update whenever the DOM is modified to create/remove elements.

I imagine this is a (somewhat) common case, which seems to have some handling in major frameworks (Backbone and Prototype seem to both give some better event handling patterns), but I am trying to avoid adding another framework to the web application.  The project already has a jQuery dependency though, which I think should make this possible to do with selectors.

Does anyone know of a good pattern that would gracefully support this kind of behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Could you bind to the blur event via jQuery, like:

```
 $(document.body).on('blur', 'input', function (event) {
      $.ajax({ url: "/log/", data: {value: event.currentTarget.value} })
 })
```